# paypal verify-mobile-payment adaptive payment

Tags: mobile, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to implement the verify payment from paypal from this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

I'm using the adaptive payment call. In the response of this call there are status and senderTransactionStatus parameters, where can I find the documentation for the different values that this parameters can have? From the this doc I only see only one value per param

```
Is completed ("status": "COMPLETED")
Is complete ("senderTransactionStatus": "COMPLETED").
```

this is just not enough for me to handle all the different states that one transaction can be in. Please suggest a document where I can read about the different paypal transaction states, the paypal documentation somehow seems to be difficult to get arround. 
Thanks